# Pass global variable to laravel group route from current url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I have a route group with this structure:

```
Route::prefix('admin/{w_id}')->middleware(['auth'])->as('weblog.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomePageController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('/blogcategory', CategoryController::class);

});
```

On dashboard route I have w_id in url and when I want to redirect user to blogcategory route (from anywhere) I should pass w_id manully in route helper class, I need some thing to set in globally from current link.

For example when I using this method:

```
'route' => 'weblog.blogcategory.store'
```

I got error like :

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: weblog.blogcategory.store]
```

And I should pass w_id parameter to all route helper manually, I need set globally w_id from current url of page.
I'm developing fully separated admin area for user's weblog and weblog id is exist in all url.

Comment: your route should look like this `{{ route('weblog.blogcategory.store', ['w_id'=>1, 'something_else_id'=>'ok']) }}`

Comment: @bhucho Yes, I know but I need something to set it globally from current url, I can't use your method because I have to do many time

Comment: so you want a default value of w_id for that group

Comment: @bhucho Yes, but from current url ( request()->w_id ). I don't know how can I deploy it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid passing w_id again you will need to use `URL::defaults()`, it will create a default value for your parameter.
You can use a middleware to pass the default value.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultWidForWeblogs
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['w_id' => /* pass the default value here*/]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now register the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` class (See more description [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#registering-middleware))

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...

    'pass_wid' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultWidForWeblogs::class,
];
```

---

Then use that middleware
So for your route group

```
Route::prefix('admin/{w_id}')->middleware(['auth', 'pass_wid'])->as('weblog.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomePageController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('/blogcategory', CategoryController::class);

});
```

---

See in docs about [default values to Url](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values)