# How do I override the "route" helper method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to add some default value to a specific parameter if there isn't any value already set.
I've already tried the following code in the `register` function of the `AppServiceProvider` class but it's not working:

```php
$this->app->extend('route', function ($name, $parameters, $absolute, $app) {
        if (!in_array('locale', $parameters)) {
            $parameters['locale'] = app()->getLocale();
        }
        return route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
});
```

Comment: Don't mess with the `route` helper, instead use the [`Url::defaults`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values) helper.

Comment: why not use a middleware, use Url:Default() see this example as reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/65284631/9471283

Answer (score 0):

I think using a middleware will be more suited and efficient in your case, take a look at the official laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware).

And you can use `URL::defaults();` to set the default values as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values)